# google map displaying problem

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have a google map and is not displayed properly.
To see what I'm talking about check this [LINK](http://oceanplaygrounds.com/joomla2/index2.php?option=com_zoo&view=item&Itemid=3)

and click on the 2nd tab.

The map is inside a jquery accordion and if I remove the accordion the map is displayed properly. 
This is the javascript code I've used:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

//Hide (Collapse) the toggle containers on load
$(".toggle_container").hide(); 

//Switch the "Open" and "Close" state per click then slide up/down (depending on open/close state)
$("h2.trigger").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
    return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe try validating your html

```
<body> 
<h2 class="trigger"><a href="#">Availability</a></h2> 
<div class="toggle_container"> 
    <div class="block"> 
      <div id="frontend-container"> 
                <div id="frontend"></div> 
            </div> 
        </div> 

    </div> 


</body> 
</html></div>       </div> 


    </div> 

    <div class="box-b1"> 
        <div class="box-b2"> 
            <div class="box-b3"></div> 
        </div> 
    </div> 

</div>              

    </div> 

</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

what's going on here?

```
</body> 
</html></div>       </div>
```

Comment: thanks, I've made some cleaning, I said some because i use Joomla and a component called Zoo and all of the stuff is dynamically added,anyway the problem persist only if I use the accordion, if I remove the accordion the map is displaying properly,

Comment: try creating the map after the accordion is created.

Comment: so, you say to put the map outside the accordion ?

Comment: no, just make sure the jquery is done creating the accordion before drawing the map. Use a timeout for a easy test.

Comment: oh, the jquery is creating the accordion before drawing the map, but some strange thing is happening: I have already a jquery library loaded by default but the accordion works only if I add another jquery library in the code, if I remove the jquery library from the code the map it is displayed proper but the accordion doesn't work.